# Convert HTML selector into Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am creating a script that turns HTML selectors into customisable menus. I need to return a nested Object(like Fig 2) from my HTML.

i.e return this
    **Fig 1**

```
 <select id="orderBy">                  
    <option value="order-by=newest&">newest</option> 
    <option value="order-by=relevance&">relevance</option>
 </select>
<select id="searchBy">                  
    <option value="search-by=name&">name</option> 
    <option value="search-by=number&">number</option>
</select>
```

as an Object like so:
    **Fig 2**

```
selectors = [       
    {"id":"orderBy", "options" : [
        {"value":"search-by=newest&", "name":"search-by=relevance&"}
    ]},
    {"id":"searchBy", "options" : [
        {"value":"search-by=name&", "name":"search-by=number&"}
    ]}
];
```

My code so far, although this doesn't work.

```
var selector = new Object;

//Find all select boxes and push their ID's' into selector
$("#filter").find("select").map(function(i){
  selector[i] = this.id;
});

//Find all select boxes and push their ID's' into selector
$("#" + selector[i]).find("option").map(function(i){
  optionText[i] = $(this).text();
  optionValue[i] = $(this).val();
});
```

**Summary**

The above code returns

```
Object {0: "orderBy", 1: "searchBy"}.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Higher level objective still seems overly broad. Not clear if you mean whole page or just specific tags or specific sections of page. `i` is clearly undefined in second code snippet but not clear if you are happy with the object created yet either. In short...you should really be more specific about where you are having issues

Comment: @charlietfl - I have edited the question to hopefully narrow it down. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create an array using `map()` you need to return an object within the callback.

You probably want something more like

```
var data = $('#container select').map(function(){
   // create array of option objects for this select instance
   var opts = $(this).children().map(function(){
      // return an object for each element of array
     return{
       text:  $(this).text(),
       value: this.value
     }
   }).get();
   // now an object for this select instance
   var obj={
     id:      this.id,
     options: opts // array from above   
   }
   return obj;   

}).get();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tsuw6kaa/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is a really good answer, thank you. Although I will settle on your answer, I'd be interested to know whether .map() or .serializeArray(); is the better way to go? I've been reading about it since posting the question.

Comment: All depends on objective which is still very unclear. `serializeArray()` will only return the name and current value of each select

Comment: Ultimately what I'm trying to do is create a script that changes the <select> html elements into a reformatted menu that is fully customisable. The reason I wanted it as an object is so I can interate through it and output as I wish. Does that make sense?

Comment: Then serilaizeArray will not do what you want and you need your own mapping similar to what I did as answer although you could skip the map and build the menu items on the fly also ... do it on a per select basis inside `each`

Comment: Cool, thanks! Good to know i was on the right track even though I fell short of the mark! Cheers for your help, really appreciated!

Comment: If you had been more specific about objective and showed some sort of expected results my answer would have actually been quite different

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by higher level situation.